# How to dynamically add/remove function from context menu in Openlayers?

Tags: javascript, gis, contextmenu, openlayers

I'm using openlayers 4 and I have setup context menu in my application, but I want to be able to add and remove functions inside context menu dynamically.

I've checked their documentation at https://github.com/jonataswalker/ol-contextmenu and I found code for adding new function (although I'm looking for adding function as a submenu item rather than menu item) but I couldn't find how to remove specific server

Comment: There are methods provided to add to the end and to remove the first and last items, but apart from that it seems you would need to do what the example code does, which is clear the menu then rebuild it.

Comment: Thanks mike for the answer, but how can I write function with arguments for context menu.

Comment: You could use splice to update the item array and sub arrays.  Here is an update the the jsfiddle in your link https://jsfiddle.net/xuf6m37r/3/